# Difference between @Qualifier in spring framework and javax.inject?

Tags: java, spring, micronaut

I am trying to map beans by name in Micronaut framework and looking from something similar to `@Qualifier` in Spring. An example would be helpful for this scenario.

Comment: Beans don't really have names in the Micronaut application context in the same way that beans in a Spring application context have names and generally are not needed.  What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have two beans in the application that get wired by `@Named`, both beans created by the configuration data source in application.yml. When I am testing I want to inject two beans that I create to the `@Named` variables mentioned previously.

I am referring - https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-sql/latest/guide/

Comment: "When I am testing I want to inject two beans that I create to the @Named variables mentioned previously." - Do you want to inject them into a collection/array or do you want to inject them as separate properties?

Comment: I need two beans for an object that I am injecting in the constructor. I would be injecting mock beans. The data sources are for SQL and I have @Named in the constructor:

Comment: `@Singleton`
class FirstRepository @Inject constructor(
  `@Named`("oracle") private val sqlFactoryOne: SqlSessionFactory,
  `@Named`("mysql") private val sqlFactoryTwo: SqlSessionFactory,

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to be

> @field:Named("beanName")

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues/17